# jQuery alert fire 4 / 10 times, why?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

```
jQuery ->
if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
        url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
        if $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 130
            alert "to much alerts"
            $('.pagination').text('Fetching more users...')
```

The problem is like in title... When I scroll down page it display message x 5/10. So code work but why it is executed so many times?

Comment: you should debounce the onscroll event which is called on most browsers/device on each pixel scrolling

Comment: Once your condition get's true, it remains true as long as you scroll down. So it get's executed so many time. You need to use flag to restrict this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are scrolling you can see that its not fluid but window jumps few pixels at time. Scroll event is triggered with every 'jump'. So it takes about 5/10 depending how u scroll to get out of if statement. I think everything works fine in such sense.